# How to add Text Field, Edit Field and Button on the top of map?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I want to add text field, edit field and button on the top of map but it is not working correctly. Please tell me how can i resolve this issue. My map_activity.xml file is given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
            android:text="@string/xyz"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:labelFor="@+id/editText1">
            <requestFocus/>
             </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"
            android:onClick="geoLocate"
            android:text="@string/abc" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

please tell me what should i do?

Comment: what problem you are getting

Comment: thank u i have done solve my problem.

Comment: if my answer help you please accept it as answer :)

Comment: ok thank u so much... :) but at this time i facing one more problem. can i ask to u?

Comment: private boolean initMap() {
   if (myMap == null){
   SupportMapFragment mapFrag =
     (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
   myMap = mapFrag.getMap();
   }
  return (myMap != null);
  }

Comment: in this code i m getting error at boolean word, Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error, insert "VariableDeclarators" to complete 
  LocalVariableDeclaration
 - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
 - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete LocalVariableDeclarationStatement
 - Illegal modifier for parameter $missing$; only final is permitted

Comment: this is method , call it inside you class (Like MapACtivity etc ), not inside any method(may be onCreate)

Comment: ok thanks again... i have solve my problem... :) :) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add property `android:layout_below` for map fragment.

Below is code :

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
            android:text="@string/xyz"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:labelFor="@+id/editText1">
            <requestFocus/>
             </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"
            android:onClick="geoLocate"
            android:text="@string/abc" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <fragment
 android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I added the line you recommend. Unfortunately I am still not able to click and drag a text on the Map layout...